# Update a TextBox Text from a ListBox Item when other TextBox TextChanged its triggered inside the same listbox item WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, listbox

Picture with the listBox item including the two textboxes and how it should work:
[image]

The problem is that I got a ListBox item which includes some objects along two textboxes, one textbox is meant to be written it, and when the TextBox TextChanged is triggered, it should call a function which updates the second textbox which is read only.

The next code is the class that its used to give the values to all the objects inside the ListBox item.

How I could update the second textbox when the first textbox is TextChanged triggered? Thanks!

```
public class ListBoxSneakerItems
{
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Size { get; set; }
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public double StorePrice { get; set; }
    public double PayoutPrice { 
        get { return "void call" } 
        }
}
```

Comment: What have you got so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ItemTemplate

This is my code
MainWindow:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication.Wpf.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication.Wpf"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Margin="5">
                        <TextBox x:Name="source" FontSize="16" Text="{Binding Path=ItemTitle}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                        <TextBlock FontSize="16" Text="{Binding ElementName=source, Path=Text, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Model of Item:

```
public class ItemModel
{
    public string ItemTitle { get; set; }
}
```

And main window Viewmodel:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<ItemModel> Items { get; set; }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<ItemModel>
        {
            new ItemModel { ItemTitle = "exemple title 1" },
            new ItemModel { ItemTitle = "exemple title 2" },
        };
    }
}
```

Result:
[image]

upd:

And project:

[image]

UPD 2:

else you can use UserControl:

just move the template to a custom control and set UserControl as the template for the ListBox

UserControl:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication.Wpf.ItemBoxTemplate"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication.Wpf"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800" Background="White">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Margin="5">
            <TextBox x:Name="source" FontSize="16" Text="{Binding Path=ItemTitle}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
            <TextBlock FontSize="16" Text="{Binding ElementName=source, Path=Text, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And MainWindow:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication.Wpf.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication.Wpf"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <local:ItemBoxTemplate />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The rest of the code remains unchanged.